# Is it possible to have a closed form solution of this coupled non-autonomous differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider this set of coupled equations
\begin{align}
i \dot a(t) &= f(t) b(t)\\
i \dot b(t) & = f(t)^* a(t)
\end{align}
where $f(t)=\lambda \cos(\beta t)e^{-i\gamma t}$  and the operation $^*$ denotes complex conjugation. Here $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ are t independent constants and $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

Is it possible to find a closed form solution of this equation?

Comment: What is the star? You seem to be missing an equal sign. This is a first order linear system: what exactly goes wrong if you use the usual approach to solve such things?

Comment: Can't you just solve for b in the first equation and replace that in the second one, solve the resulting 2nd order linear equation for a, and then find b?

Comment: Sorry, star is complex conjugate. but b is also time dependent, so how do I solve for it?

Comment: In which context does this system of differential equations appears ? It resembles some kind of Schrödinger equation or Rabi oscillations.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate your first equation:
$$ i \ddot{a} = \dot{f} b + f \dot{b}$$
Work to isolate $\dot{b}$ in terms of $a$ and $\dot{a}$. Use the first equation again to substitute for $b$:
$$ i \ddot{a}/f - \dot{f} i \dot{a}/f^2 = \dot{b}.$$
Now use this in your second equation to eliminate b.
$$ - \ddot{a}/f + \dot{f} \dot{a}/f^2 =  f^\ast a. $$
Now you have a second order equation for $a$:
$$ \ddot{a} - \frac{\dot{f}}{f} \dot{a} + f f^\ast a = 0. $$
To me, this does not appear analytically solvable. Perhaps a clever change of variables can remove the time dependence of the coefficients. One you had $a$, you could then use it to obtain $b$.

Depending on your application, you may find it useful to linearize the equations about interesting points in their phase space, so you can then solve them approximately.

You might also benefit from the short time solution: $\ddot{a} + i \gamma \dot{a} + \lambda^2 a = 0 $.